# SQL Server embedded CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I go about writing a query where I want to get the last value?

For example I have a table with with tasks, 1-4 for each parent workflow.
I then have a completed column with a 1 or 0.

I would like to return 1 value, Task 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 depending if the task is complete.

I tried an embedded CASE statement, but it would always returns value 4.

There has to be a better way.

```
SELECT 
    Estimate.EstimateID, Estimate.EstimateNo, 
    CASE 
       WHEN TransWorkFlow.OwnerID = Estimate.EstimateID 
          THEN
             CASE 
                WHEN TransWorkFlowDetails.TaskNo = 1 AND TransWorkFlowDetails.Completed = 0 
                   THEN 1
                ELSE 
                   CASE 
                      WHEN TransWorkFlowDetails.TaskNo = 2 AND TransWorkFlowDetails.Completed = 0 
                         THEN 2
                      ELSE 
                         CASE
                            WHEN TransWorkFlowDetails.TaskNo = 3 AND TransWorkFlowDetails.Completed = 0 
                               THEN 3
                            ELSE 
                               CASE 
                                  WHEN TransWorkFlowDetails.TaskNo = 4 AND TransWorkFlowDetails.Completed = 0 
                                     THEN 4
                                  ELSE 4 
                               END 
                         END 
                   END 
             END
       END AS TaskCompleted
FROM 
    TransWorkFlow 
INNER JOIN
    TransWorkFlowDetails ON TransWorkFlow.TransWorkFlowID = TransWorkFlowDetails.TransWorkFlowID 
INNER JOIN
    Estimate ON TransWorkFlow.OwnerID = Estimate.EstimateID
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this can be simplified into one simple `CASE` statement

```
SELECT 
  e.EstimateID,
  e.EstimateNo,
  CASE WHEN td.Completed = 0 AND td.TaskNo IN (1,2,3,4) THEN td.TaskNo ELSE 4 END AS TaskCompleted
FROM TransWorkFlow t
INNER JOIN TransWorkFlowDetails td ON t.TransWorkFlowID = td.TransWorkFlowID
INNER JOIN Estimate e ON t.OwnerID = e.EstimateID;
```

Note:

- we're using aliases like `t`, `td` and `e` to shorten the code
- we got rid of your initial `CASE` check, because it's covered by the `INNER JOIN`
- `TaskNo` seems to be your check condition and also output, let's can reference that in `THEN` part

Comment: Okay, this help reduce the size of my query, thank you. Now I have to solve the second part of my issue. I would like the query to stop at the first zero in Completed and return the TaskNo and stop parsing. I just need to see the last TaskNo not completed.

Comment: That is another question, but as a hint you just need to add `TOP` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: If this answer helped you, consider marking it as accepted. Here's how: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Answer (score 1):

Not really clear what you are trying to do here but I think that wall of case expressions could be simplified to this.

```
case when TransWorkFlowDetails.Completed = 0
    AND TransWorkFlowDetails.TaskNo in (1, 2, 3, 4)
    THEN TransWorkFlowDetails.TaskNo
    ELSE
        --whatever you want here
    END
```

Comment: This will not work. I need a single output. I need the task number when the query hits the first 0 then stop.

Comment: Then perhaps you could share ALL of the requirements from the beginning. You could accomplish that by using ROW_NUMBER or perhaps top 1. But without ddl, sample data and desired output this is just guess work. Check out [this article](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for ideas on what to post.

Comment: Okay, so I have Estimates. They have workflow tasks (1-4). They have a status of completed = 1 and not completed = 0. I want to know which task (1-4) has not been completed. BUT I do not want to know all the tasks that are not completed, just the first one, basically I want to know at what step the workflow is. This is also a sub-query of a much larger query. I tried FIRST_VALUE, but I did not get the desired result.

Comment: That brief and somewhat vague description does not provide the kinds of details needed for others to be able to help you. Please see the link I posted above. I suspect the solution is pretty simple once the question is understood.